# Mod Rewrite question with regex's

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

Im trying to do this sort of rewrite that only affects some urls to make them go to anchors.

So if I see this request:

```
/somedir/trigger/something
```

I want to transform it to this request. I can guarantee there will be no slash after the trigger. The "something" part is going to be a alpha-numeric string every time. The "trigger" part is also alpha-numeric only, but I have multiple values for trigger. The "result" part is a constant alpha-numeric string that will never change.

```
/somedir/result#something
```

and the trigger can be maybe 4 or 5 different strings, but the result will always be the same. So I tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^/somedir/(type1|type2|type3|type4)/(.*)$ /somedir/result#$2
```

i thought $1 would be the type it catches, and $2 to be the thing i want to find and stick at the end. This doesnt work though, and if anyone knows how to do this right that would help me out

Comment: This is not a programming question.  I suggest asking at http://serverfault.com

Comment: The people at Serverfault might say: *"regex-es: that's Stackoverflow!"*. A bit of both worlds, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to work. The hash is not part of the HTTP request, the browser will not transmit it, only use it internally to jump to the right position.